# Communication between local and remote website

Tags: php, local, communication, remote-server

I have a php website, that has to run locally on a raspberry pi.
The website contains commands that controls a hardware device.

The local URSL would look like: http://localhostname
The remote URL would look like: https://www.url.com/project

The file structure (simplified) is:
local raspberry pi: index.php
remote server: login.php and database.php

The index.php is supposed to include the database.php in order to build up the database connection and handle the data transfer.

I have two problems that I don't know how to handle.

1. On the one side I do not want the database php file stored locally on the rapsberry pi. This way everybody could see the credentials. On the other side I can not include the database.php file in the index.php, because it is remote and php doesn't allow that.
2. SESSION and COOKIE handling is a problem as well. The Login (login.php) procedure is stored on the remote server. As soon as the user logs in, SESSION and COOKIE information gets stored. Those information are valid for the remote servers URL ("/"). As soon as the navigation would go back to the local Raspberry Pi the SESSION and COOKIE wouldn't be valid anymore as the domain/hostname changed.. This way I can not check if the users login was successful. The index.php shouldn't be accessible by the user as long as the user hasn't successfully logged in.

Comment: So basically login is done thru the remote site whereas the functionality is handled locally? You could make it so that the local side polls (or webhooks) who is logged in on the remote server.

Comment: Correct, so instead of using database credentials you mean that using a Rest(ful) call instead?

Comment: Where is the database?

Comment: You can include remote Php files, but that can be problematic.

Comment: @Daniel, keep the database credentials. On the remote side. The remote side could then have a script that returns all of who is logged in. The local side could use a secure `curl` call to get those results.

Comment: @Progrock: The database is on the remote server.

Comment: @GetSet: Sounds fine for me, following question for me is the curl would need a username or uid. As the site is local, the index.php won't have this information in order to check against the database...

Comment: @Daniel your remote site would have this information correct? I suppose what I'm suggesting, for clarity, is the remote site does all the authentication for users. The local side queries the remote site for users who are logged in. `the curl would need a username or uid` .. this could be to a password protected folder on the remote site that holds the script to query all logged in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make the index.php POST the credentials (username & password?) as parameters to login.php and handle the response returned.

> e.g. In case of a successful login, it returns the session that I'll
>   take about in point 2. In case of a failed login return an error.
>   index.php then has to deal either with the session returned or the
>   error.

2. You can generate a custom string and store into the database to be used a session id. This way you can authorize the user through the session id stored on the rasberry pi against the database.

> e.g. on a successful login, login.php generates a random string,
>   stores it into the database and return it back to index.php which will
>   save it on the rasberry pi for further use

Comment: And what would be the appropriate way to store this random string on the raspberry pi? The solution is not meant to have a database on the pi.

Comment: maybe a local session variable if you want it secured or just save it to a text file if you don't care about security

Comment: I'm currently implementing this, I'm still struggeling. For me the second option of  your answer suits best. The user enters the login.php (external web server) enters his credentials, the random string gets generated and stored to the external web servers database. 
Let's say a week later the user opens the index.php. The index.php os locally stored on the user's rapsberry pi (this has to be so), now how do I check against the sessid in the database. While being on the login.php (remote side) I can not set a local session variable that is supposed to be set on the local raspberry pi...